# I receive no data from server after multiple POST requests

Tags: php, jquery, post, server

I've been struggling with a problem where multiple POST requests seemingly crash the server (site won't load, no requests allowed) for a couple minutes. GET requests do not cause this issue.

**This isn't a code issue, the code works fine**

It's likely something with my server config.

Example of Frontend JS:

```
$(".searchbox").keyup(function() {
  var data = $('.searchbox').val();
      $.ajax({
        url: "../assets/php/graphenesearch.php",
        method: "POST",
        data: {
          data: data
        },
        async: true,
        dataType: "html"
      }).done(function(msg) {
        $(".search-output").html(msg);
      });
});
```

Example of Backend PHP:

```
$input = $_POST['data'];

echo $input;
```

Even with this simple of code, I'm having issues. So it's clearly with the number of requests and not the amount of data being passed.

The server allows ~40 requests, but then stops functioning.

I receive this error:

```
POST http://www.graphenesearch.co/assets/php/graphenesearch.php net::ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE
```

It's probably something obvious right? Server config?

Comment: try with remove `async: true,`

Comment: @Craig_VG I think that's not your code problem ....

Comment: @Aniruddha Chakraborty That's the conclusion I came to as well, it must be server related, but I haven't a clue what it could be.

Comment: ok , would it be great if i try to explain little briefly in a detailed answer ?

Comment: Start by checking your php-error log and your web servers error log.

Comment: @AniruddhaChakraborty Sure!

Comment: Tried to explain :) @Craig_VG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving you a detailed answer if there is any problem with request handling in server side there will be several problems

1. Server Network ( You don't have any problem with you code , sometime some data center face internet connection problem . DDOS attacks on data center can also cause damage on processing request )
2. Getting too much request ( Every web server have some limitation because on server can not handle too much request . In Low quality shared hosting or Low quality OpenCV hosting you'll face this kind of problem . Even I faced this kind of a problem)
3. PHP Configuration error , you'r php might not configured correctly . maybe that is causing all damage . Open the php log file to check there. after configuration fix PLEASE RESTART YOUR SERVER.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I think it is #2 as I have some pretty low quality server hosting for this site. Can you recommend a good option for hosting a server that can take many incoming connections? Thanks so much!

Comment: Planing to host on a shared hosting or vps server ? if you want to choose among shared hosting i would suggest bluehost.com  . if you want to use vps then ramnode,digitalocean or vpsdime is the best.