# Server does not respond after multiple post requests within a minute

Tags: php, mysql, server, hosting

The problem is that I have GoDaddy shared hosting and deployed an ecommerce store build on PHP. Now when the web service receives multiple requests within a minute or so it stops responding for at least a couple of minutes to only my IP address and not anyone else. It is behaving as if is limited to server one single IP for a limited number of requests.

Below is the way I am testing it because frontend is made on Angular 7 and it doesn't matter. Both the ways returns same results:

```
setInterval(function(){
  $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '--webservice--',
      data: { test: 'test' },
      success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
      }
  })
}, 1000)
```

Server Side:

```
$input = $_POST['test'];
echo json_encode($input); die;
```

Now you can see what I have done is that I have created an Interval which will hit the service every second just to check after how many service hits, the server stops responding. Result I am getting is this almost every time:

[image: You can see the result here]

For some strange reason, if I convert this to GET request. It works perfectly even if I reduce time interval to 100 ms, it kept receiving response for 200+ requests within 10 maybe 15 seconds. The problem exists with POST requests and not get requests.

I have had a long discussion with the hosting provider also & they say that the server is configured correctly and whatever the issue is, it is with your content.

Can anyone tell me what is happening and how can I fix this issue please?

I have came across a similar problem someone was facing and almost same issue if not exact:

[I receive no data from server after multiple POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34986709/i-receive-no-data-from-server-after-multiple-post-requests).

But the thing is that he wasn't assured from the hosting provider but I do and I am not happy with it.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. By searching through the internet, I got to know that Godaddy will block the access of an IP to a server, if it gets more than 40 POST requests per minute. You step also worked for me also.